# jQuery Form Validator Password error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, passwords

i am validating my form with http://formvalidator.net/ and getting one error. I have a three fields for changing the password.

1. Old Password
2. New Password
3. Cofirm Password

When user enter their old, new and cofirm password then validator showing me the below error you can see the picture below. I don't know why this error occur. I guess its matching the very first password field how to get rid off this issue?

Here you can see the error

[image]

My Code

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-form-validator/2.1.27/jquery.form-validator.min.js"></script>

<script>    
    $.validate({
    modules : 'security'
});
</script>

<form name="form2" id="form2" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <p>
          <label>Password</label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pass_confirmation" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$" data-validation-error-msg="" data-validation-optional="true">
        </p>

        <p>
          <label>New Password</label>
          <input type="password" placeholder="New Password" name="new_pass_confirmation" data-validation="custom" data-validation-regexp="^(?=.*\d)[0-9a-zA-Z]{6,}$" data-validation-error-msg="" data-validation-optional="true">
        </p>

        <p> Repeat password
          <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" name="pass" data-validation="confirmation" data-validation-optional="true">
        </p>       

        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="submit_edit_two"  value="Update" />
        </p>

      </form>
```

One file i've located in js folder for calling security module, thats security.js. Without this file security validator can't be work.
You can download security module js file from [here](http://formvalidator.net/js/form-validator/security.js).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the name of new_pass_confirmation to pass_confirmation, it will solve the issue.